# Longest sub-string in alphabetical order gives unexpected output

Tags: python, python-3.x

My question is somewhat related to this closed one - [Longest substring in alphabetical order](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19581585/8572503), but not properly.

Here is my python code for printing the longest substring of `String s` in which the letters occur in alphabetical order.

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
chow = ''
stuff = []
for e in s:
    if(s.find(e) < (len(s)-1)):     #fix indexoutofrange
       if(e <= s[s.find(e) + 1]):   #just checking the next char
           chow = chow + e          #sum up
       else:
           stuff.append(chow)
           chow = ''                # reset chow
    else:
        stuff.append(chow)          #edit

if(len(stuff)==1):
    print(stuff[0])
elif(len(stuff)==0):
    print('')
else:
    print(max(stuff,key=len))
```

I know someone will find a better code at StackOverflow. But, my question is why I'm not getting the expected behavior of the code?

---

**Test Cases:**

- 'azcbobobegghakl' → '*begg*' | **'beggh' is right**
- 'abcbcd' → '*ab*' | **'abc' is right.**
- 'afzeolnfabcdefoooda' → '*fabcdef*' | **'abcdefooo' is right**

What I can see is, the last character isn't sometimes adding or sometimes, the first character is the wrong one.

*Please answer specifically the error area and describe why it is instead of fixing the code.*

Comment: For your last test case, wouldn't the correct answer to 'afzeolnfabcdefoooda' be 'abcdefo'?

Comment: Actually `abcdefooo` as it's implied that it can be the same in the code with the `<=` operator

Comment: yes, `abcdefooo` . Actually, I was talking about the first character `f` before that in this case.

Comment: Agreed, check my answer. It's a strange case of you're getting close to the answer, but more because of your choice of strings. It's because it's looking for characters at the start, it just so happens, that your strings kind of work in this case.

Comment: Yes, I checked it. It's a bit complex but fine :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in the other answer, you need to append when there is the exception as well. But furthermore, the find function only finds the first instance of that letter. So you should discard the string you've already processed (easier than tediously tracking it with a counter).

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
s_working = s
chow = ''
stuff = []
for e in s:
    if(s_working.find(e) < (len(s_working)-1)):     #fix indexoutofrange
       if(e <= s_working[s_working.find(e) + 1]):   #just checking the next char
           chow = chow + e          #sum up
       else:
           chow = chow + e #[FIX]Add the last char before append to list
           stuff.append(chow)
           chow = ''                # reset chow
    s_working = s_working[1:]       # discards the already processed string
    else:
        chow = chow + e
        stuff.append(chow)

print(max(stuff,key=len))
```

Tested on all of the examples and it works. Now adjusted for the comment examples, and captures the last letter too if it's included.

Comment: @Toaster updated to capture the last letter, and if there's no others, still append it to `stuff`. If there are multiple longest strings, obviously with `max` it will return the first

Comment: Yes. I looked at it. you also fixed the last in case of a-z :-D :-D  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

For the last character disapper, I think the issue is that you are not adding the last character before append your string to list. This issue can be fixed by the following fix:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
chow = ''
stuff = []
for e in s:
    if(s.find(e) < (len(s)-1)):     #fix indexoutofrange
       if(e <= s[s.find(e) + 1]):   #just checking the next char
           chow = chow + e          #sum up
       else:
           chow = chow + e #[FIX]Add the last char before append to list
           stuff.append(chow)
           chow = ''                # reset chow

print(max(stuff,key=len))
```

Comment: Why are people upvoting this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not the answer you looking for but I wrote smiler code a while ago. It finds alphabetically continuous character groups. Finding the longest one can be easily implemented.

```
base_string = "afzeolnfabcdefoooda"
tmp = []
_group = []

for _index, _char in enumerate(base_string):
    try:
        _next_char =  base_string[_index + 1]

        if  _char <= _next_char:
            # add chars to list if they are alphabetically ordered
            _group.append(_char)
        else:
            # if they are not, add the char the current group, add group to list, and create an empty one
            _group.append(_char)
            tmp.append(_group)
            _group = []

    except IndexError:
        # end of the string there is no _next_char,
        # add the _char to current group and `break` the loop
        _group.append(_char)
        tmp.append(_group)
        break
```

Result:

```
[['a', 'f', 'z'], ['e', 'o'], ['l', 'n'], ['f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'o', 'o', 'o'], ['d'], ['a']]
```